# Getting the completed image to view in scrollview

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

Hi this is the extension of the question which i have ask earlier

[stop the stackpanel items inside scroll viewer to be at the display left side when scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413068/stop-the-stackpanel-items-inside-scroll-viewer-) to-be-at-the-display-left-side-wh

I can get the horizontal offset value but i need to compare two images offset, if the scroll stops in the middle i need to move the image to get the full view kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop the scroll.
By cons, you can display your image and detect the event Flick ([gestures WP7](http://adamkinney.com/blog/2010/09/23/windows-phone-7-gestures-cheat-sheet/)) to change the displayed image and use an animation (use blend).